# Terminal printing results at another location?

Tags: python, terminal, nltk

Everyone. I am a beginner programmer, and I can't seem to find this information anywhere on the web, so I am hoping you guys can help. My problem is that sometimes when I try to print a result the terminal spits back something like "" or "", rather than the result. I am actually following very short, very simple lines of code straight out of a book and still getting these results.

Here are some examples to better show what is happening.

In the first example, "potato" is just the file handle name of a random text document.

```
import nltk
def diversity(potato):
    return len(potato) / len(set(potato))
print diversity(potato)
#prints <function diversity at 0x107b5a848>">
```

or

```
import nltk
print bigrams(['make', 'me', 'some', 'bigrams'])
#prints <generator object bigram at 0x1088a4d20>
```

However in the examples in the text book just show the correct results printing. If it is at all important to know, I am specifically working with the book "Natural Language Processing with Python" by Bird, Klein, and Loper, and I am running Python 2.7.9.

Can anyone explain what is happening and how I can get around this? These are very simple lines of code with very simple answers, so the fact that my terminal seemingly refuses to print the correct answers is irritating and worrisome. Thank you!

Comment: can you provide the full source for the first example? What is `potato`? Also: what is your desired output for the second example?

Comment: added it! "Potato" is just a random file with text in it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second example is very easy to explain.

The return value from the `nltk.bigrams` function is a [generator](https://www.jeffknupp.com/blog/2013/04/07/improve-your-python-yield-and-generators-explained/).
If you want to see the actual values that it returns you need to iterate over it and print its values:

```
In [11]: for bigram in  nltk.bigrams(['make', 'me', 'some', 'bigrams']):
   ....:     print bigram
   ....:     
('make', 'me')
('me', 'some')
('some', 'bigrams')
```

Comment: Thank you! Do you think that the reason why the book is able to simply print the answer as I original typed it is because of some sort of compatibility issue?

Comment: can you provide a link to the book (as far as I can tell there also is an online version?) or provide the exact code and output from the book. I should be able to explain it with that provided

Comment: Thank you so much! The book can be found here http://victoria.lviv.ua/html/fl5/NaturalLanguageProcessingWithPython.pdf
The code I am pulling is from pg 31 of the pdf (not pg 31 of the book), top of the page. Again, thank you!

Comment: I guess the bigrams part is just a mistake in the book. They call `list` on it in the [online version](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch01.html#collocations-and-bigrams) and also explain that you need to do this if you do not want the generator.